# Does docker support CentOS/RHEL now? (after 0.7 release)

Tags: centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

As this post (http://blog.docker.io/2013/11/docker-0-7-docker-now-runs-on-any-linux-distribution/) claims that docker now have "Standard Linux support" including RHEL, but in the documents (http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/installation/kernel/) it specifies that Linux version 3.8 or above is required.  RHEL and CentOS still on the kernel 2.6 stage. Can someone explain to me if they are supported or not?

Comment: I think it's more correct to say that [docker](http://tips4admin.com/blog/2013/09/how-to-install-docker-on-centos-6-4/) is available.

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed a lot on the docker-dev mailing list, and it seems that yes, with a bit of tweaking it does run on CentOS.

You can use this vagrant configuration to test if the support is good enough for you: https://github.com/blalor/vagrant-centos64-docker

If you're happy with how it works, you can then configure your CentOS with the `bootstrap.sh` script included in the aforementioned repository.